Length of a side of a double angle triangle
I need some help on this problem: In the triangle $PQR$, $\angle R = 2\angle P, PR=5, QR=4$. What is the length of $PQ$?
I constructed the triangle and have no idea what to do next. The only idea I had was that maybe the $4$ and $5$ represent a $3-4-5$ Pythagorean triple, but after closer examination, the angles would be $30$ and $60$ degrees if it were are right triangle. Please help

Note that, if it were a right triangle with side lengths $3,4,5$ the angles wouldn't be $30^{\circ}$ and  $60^{\circ}$. In fact, the $90-60-30$  triangle has the side lengths of $a,\sqrt3 a, 2a$

1/ Can you draw the figure and include it? $\quad$ 2/ Are you familiar with sine rule? If so, can you apply it to this situation?

Not a 3-4-5 triangle. But the triangle it does represent has a remarkable dissection, or two.

Here is diagram of the problem,

Applying law of sines gives,
$$\dfrac x{\sin 2\alpha}=\dfrac 4{\sin \alpha}\Rightarrow x\sin\alpha=8\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\Rightarrow x=8\cos\alpha$$
Now by applying law of cosines we have,
$$QR^2=PQ^2+PR^2-2PR.PQ\cos(\angle QPR)$$
$$x^2+25-10x\cos\alpha=16$$
Substituting $x=8\cos\alpha$ results in,
$$64\cos^2\alpha-80\cos^2\alpha=-9\Rightarrow \cos\alpha= \pm \dfrac34$$
As $x$ cannot be negative, we have $x=8\times\dfrac34=6$

Or substitute $\cos\alpha = \frac x8$ into $x^2 +25-10x\cos\alpha = 16$, in order to find $x$.

Let $\alpha$ be the value of $\angle P$ or $\frac12 \angle R$. Construct the angle bisector of $\angle R$ to meet $PQ$ at $S$:

$\triangle PSR$ has equal base angles $\alpha$, so it is isosceles:
$$PS=RS$$
Since $\angle RPQ = \angle SRQ = \alpha$ and $\angle PQR = \angle RQS$,
$$\triangle PQR \sim \triangle RQS\quad\text{(AAA)}$$
Then these corresponding lengths are in ratio:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{PQ}{RQ} &= \frac{PR+RQ}{RS+SQ}\\
\frac{PQ}{4} &= \frac{5+4}{PS+SQ}\\
PQ^2 &= 4(5+4)\\
PQ &= 6
\end{align*}$$

First render $\angle Q=180°-3\angle P$ (why?). Then the Law of Sines gives
$\dfrac{\sin(3\angle P)}{5}=\dfrac{\sin(\angle P)}{4}\tag{1}$
Now instead of memorizing the triple angle identities we may render
$\sin(3\angle P)-\sin(\angle P)=2\cos(2\angle P)\sin(\angle P)$
$=2\sin(\angle P)-4\sin^3(\angle P)\tag{2}$
where we use only the double angle formula for cosine and the trigonometric sum-product relations.
Then from (1) we have $\sin(3\angle P)=(5/4)\sin(\angle P)$; substituting this into (2) and solving (since $\angle P$ is not the largest angle it must be acute, so the sine is positive) yields
$\sin(\angle P)=\sqrt7/4$
Then from the double angle formula for sine we have
$\sin(\angle R)=2\sin(\angle P)\cos(\angle P)=(2)[\sin(\angle P)](3/4)=(3/2)\sin(\angle P)$
So the Law of Sines implies $PQ=(3/2)QR=6$.
